# Why does estimator.export_saved_model complain about missing variables after TF2 migration?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I'm doing distillation with a teacher and student BERT model and exporting the student model with `estimator.export_saved_model`. This worked fine in TF1, but I moved to TF2 to be able to use multi-gpu training and now I keep getting the following error message:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Key bert/embeddings/dense/bias not found in checkpoint
         [[{{node save/RestoreV2}}]]
```

When I investigate the node names in the checkpoints, I find that they all have a suffix of some sort which is why they can't be found e.g. `bert/embeddings/dense_21/bias`.

I assume this is some new TF2 naming thing? Why does this happen and how can I turn it off? I already tried removing the suffixes and overwriting the checkpoints, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As per [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator), the use of Estimators is discouraged with TF2, and they receive no further support except for vunerability fixes.

See the [migration guide from Estimator to Keras APIs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/migrating_estimator).